# How To Allow Wildcard Template Argument

Tags: c++, templates, matrix

I am currently writing a matrix class that will be able to support any number of rows and columns through templates. I'm stuck on how go about preventing an invalid operation (i.e. number of columns for matrix 1 ≠ number of rows for matrix 2). I could of course store the number of rows and columns and check at run time, but optimally I'd like to make this check at compile time through a "wildcard" template argument.

In other words...

I want to do this:

```
template <typename T, int R, int C>
struct mat {

    T matrix[R][C];

    void operator *=(const mat<T, C, [can be anything]> &other) {
        /* do operation */
    }

};
```

Instead of this:

```
template <typename T, int R, int C>
struct mat {

    T matrix[R][C];
    int rows = R;
    int columns = C;

    void operator *=(const mat *other) {
        if (columns != other->rows) {
            /* error */
        } else {
            /* do operation */
        }
    }

};
```

Is this possible? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me

```
template <typename T, int R, int C>
struct mat {

    T matrix[R][C];

    template <int CC>
    void operator *=(const mat<T, C, CC> &other) {
        /* do operation */
    }

};

int main()
{
    mat<int, 2, 3> m1;
    mat<int, 3, 4> m2;
    m1 *= m2;
}
```

Comment: _Not sure why my question was downvoted_, but this was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @gooroo7 Me neither, especially as the reason given was that 'its not clear what you are asking'. Seemed very clear to me.

Answer (score -3):

Define template《int K》mat《T,R,K》& operator*(const mat《T, C,K》& other)..

Comment: I am writing on tab. People are so fast to down vote.

Comment: You could write the entire answer and put it once it's finished (instead of writing something and then progressively add pieces of text)